# How do I make a launcher for multiple executables?

Tags: java, launcher

I'm trying to make a launcher for a game I like that compiles the vanilla version and the mods into one launcher. I want to make it so I can choose between the versions, maybe with a rudimentary GUI. The original versions of the game are in Java, but I'm converting them to .EXE with Launch4j, and that's working fine.

Comment: With what are you stuck? Launching an EXE from another program? Making the program per se?

Comment: It'd be also nice to know what game you create this for, so we can at least know the background.

Comment: This is not about making games but about launching an arbitrary executable that happens to be a game. This would be on-topic on http://stackoverflow.com/ where this question has most likely been answered already.

Comment: The game is Minicraft. I checked StackOverflow, it hasn't been answered. :(

Comment: I'm stuck on making the launcher. I don't have much experience, and if I really wanted to I guess I could make a Python script, but I wanna make it have MAYBE a rudimentary GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just made a BAT file (Batch program, whatever) and coded it like that. I know Batch is a dying language, but I like it and it's fairly backwards-compatible. Here's the code:

```
@echo off
:beginning
ECHO Minicraft Launcher 1.0
ECHO Coded in Microsoft Batch by Deven Blake
ECHO (C) 2017 Please reproduce with credit to the author.
ECHO.
ECHO    ^>1 Minicraft Vanilla
ECHO    ^>2 Minicraft Flash v1
ECHO    ^>3 Minicraft Flash v2
ECHO    ^>4 Minicraft Flash v3
ECHO    ^>5 Minicraft Flash v4
ECHO    ^>6 Minicraft Plus
ECHO    ^>7 Minicraft Delux
ECHO.
SET /P _inputness= Which Minicraft version would you like to play?  
IF "%_inputness%"=="1" GOTO :vanilla-mode
IF "%_inputness%"=="2" GOTO :flashmode-1
IF "%_inputness%"=="3" GOTO :flashmode-2
IF "%_inputness%"=="4" GOTO :flashmode-3
IF "%_inputness%"=="5" GOTO :flashmode-4
IF "%_inputness%"=="6" GOTO :plus-mode
IF "%_inputness%"=="7" GOTO :deluxe-mode
ECHO Option not recognized. Please input a number from one to seven.
GOTO :beginning

:vanilla-mode
minicraft.exe
GOTO :end

:flashmode-1
"minicraft online v1.exe"
GOTO :end

:flashmode-2
"minicraft online v2.exe"
GOTO :end

:flashmode-3
"minicraft online v3.exe"
GOTO :end

:flashmode-4
"minicraft online v4.exe"
GOTO :end

:plus-mode
"minicraft plus.exe"
GOTO :end

:deluxe-mode
"minicraft delux.exe"
GOTO :end

:end
```

That's not the final edit before I release it on Github (with mention that I didn't create the original games, I only made the launcher), but it's a nice start. Thanks, you guys, for trying to help.

**UPDATE: [Minicraft Ultimate on GitHub](https://github.com/RandomGuyDTB/Minicraft-Ultimate)**

Comment: What makes you think batch is a dying language? It's the built in scripting language for windows.

Comment: @Bálint Microsoft is slowly phasing out Batch for PowerShell, which I hate.