# How would I make a self updating launcher for my game in Java?

Tags: java, launcher

I have a game I am working on, and I want to make a launcher for it. I am having trouble finding information on how to do it in Java (my video game is programmed in Java, so I do not want to use C#, and I want to avoid C++ unless I really have to).

How can I do this?

Comment: There has been question about launchers in this site before, which I believe you can find useful. Did you try a search? Assuming you did and what you found wasn't useful, can you be more specific on your particular case? Addendum: try also the deployment tag.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I did do a little searching. Basically all I want to do is to have a launcher which on start tries sees if the game needs to update and if it needs to update  it updates. I am sorry it's kind of late at night and I need to go to bed, I will try to provide more detail in the morning.

Comment: As Therapt says, we have [existing Q&A about building a launcher for Java games that you can find with a search](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=launcher+%5Bjava%5D), including [How do I make a launcher for multiple executables?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/138989/39518) and [How can I make a self-updating game launcher?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/102920/39518). The latter, despite being closed, contains a Java code sample to do the job. How have you tried implementing your launcher based on your research thus far, and what do you need that differs from this?

Comment: I just found that article after more searching, it does it's job pretty well. Thanks!